# single quotes and double quotes in python strings

Tags: python, linux

I want to call a python function `pexpect.spawn(cmd)`, where cmd is a string as below:

```
ssh -t kity@192.199.61.205 'sudo nohup bash -c "./tcp_sender > /dev/null 2>&1 &"'
```

the ip addresses are always changing, so it is something like:

```
ssh -t kity@%s 'sudo nohup bash -c "./tcp_sender > /dev/null 2>&1 &"' %host_ip
```

there are several `'` and `"`, I'm at a loss how to deal with it
so basically, it is about how to deal with escaping in python strings
and when there is a variable substring, how to deal with it

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use triple quotes:

```
"""ssh -t kity@{0} 'sudo nohup bash -c "./tcp_sender > /dev/null 2>&1 &"'""".format(ip_address)
```

Comment: triple `"`? , why not `'''`?

Comment: either one should work, I'm just more accustomed to seeing doubles used for triple quotes

Comment: @misteryes they both work but using three `"`s is far more common (or idiomatic) in existing python code. This of course doesn't force you into using it thought. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cameron Sparr has already given the general-purpose answer.

But in your specific case, you probably don't need this.

[`pexpect.spawn`](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn) accepts either a command-and-arguments string *or* a command string and a list of separate argument strings. And the same is true for most similar methods in other libraries (like everything in the standard library `subprocess` module).

So, you only need to make each argument into a string, like this:

```
pexpect.spawn('ssh', ['-t', 'kity@192.199.61.205', 'sudo nohup bash -c "./tcp_sender > /dev/null 2>&1 &"'])
```

In fact, the documentation specifically suggests this, for exactly this reason:

> The second form of spawn (where you pass a list of arguments) is useful
>   in situations where you wish to spawn a command and pass it its own
>   argument list. This can make syntax more clear.

Of course in your case, you're actually spawning a command with a list of arguments… one of which is itself a command to spawn and a list of arguments (`sudo`), and so on a few steps down the line (`nohup`, `bash`, and finally `tcp_sender`), and obviously `pexpect` can only help with the first of those steps. Fortunately, in this case, that's all you need.

If you *do* need more, there are some libraries out there that can generate POSIX-style quoted strings out of argument lists (basically the reverse of [`shlex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html)), but the few times I've needed one, the one I found turned out to be buggy and I ended up rewriting it myself… It's actually not that complicated (basically, just escape everything then quote all arguments). But hopefully you'll never have to do this.